# HTTP 401 Authentication Required

Tags: php

I'm getting a 401 forbidden on this code-Authorization required.
Could someone correct and rewrite the code for me?

```
$vdata= file_get_contents('https://api.vimeo.com/videos?query='.$search.'&page='.$p.'&per_page=5&access_token='.$vimeo_token.'');
```

Comment: what does the vimeo api say how a request should look like? Sure the token is correct?

Comment: I'm guessing that you haven't obtain an access token yet. To obtain it, you have to go through their OAuth flow first.